# Why does Google Maps give different coordinates from what was entered

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-labels

When I enter the coordinates 37°01.67'N  027°25.12'E into google maps it gives me the pin in the correct place, but seems to change those coordinates and gives conflicting results

[image: screenshot of what I mean]

Answer (score 1):

Latitude and longitude are specified as degrees, minutes and seconds. In your coordinates, you specify `37°01.67'`, which means "37 degrees, 1.67 minutes". 0.67 minutes is the same as 40.2 seconds, which is what Google Maps shows (`37°01'40.2"` or "37 degrees, 1 minute, 40.2 seconds").

In other words, it's the same number, just written differently.